# Datalist Pagination

Tags: c#, pagination, datalist

im doing data pagination by using this code :

http://www.aspdotnetcodes.com/DataList_Dynamic_Paging_PagedDataSource.aspx

its work perfectly, but my problem is :

i dont want to show large page numbers like this  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 ...

i want just get a bloc of 4 pages     1 2 3 4  and after clicking next the next bloc apear

thx for helping

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just change

```
 for (int i = 0; i < pds.PageCount; i++)
```

to

```
 for (int i = 0; i < pds.PageCount && i < 4; i++)
```

Comment: Hi, ok your proposition is for limiting the lage page numbers but how generat the next bloc 5 6 7 8 thx for your fast reply

Comment: Unless this is ASP.NET, you probably should look at custom paging; don't have experience with that though.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.pageddatasource.iscustompagingenabled.aspx

Comment: Yes its ASP.NETn can you assite me to accomplish this task thx

Comment: Not really -- for ASP.NET, you'll probably have to rewrite this from scratch and I don't really have time for that... sorry.

Comment: Alternatively, you can see if there's a 3rd party control that could do this for you, like http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/aspnet/webdatagrid.aspx#Overview

Answer (score 0):

This is a c# 2.0 way, you might consider using an Enumerable.Range instead of for loops

```
PagedDataSource = new PagedDataSource();
PagedDataSource.DataSource = _yourData;
PagedDataSource.AllowPaging = true;
PagedDataSource.PageSize = 20;
PagedDataSource.CurrentPageIndex = PageNumber; // get from session, viewstate, ...

if (PagedDataSource.PageCount > 1)
{
    rptDataPager.Visible = true;
    rptDataPager.DataSource = GetPageRange(10); // try with 4 as you requested
    rptDataPager.DataBind();
}
else
    rptDataPager.Visible = false;

yourRepeater.DataSource = PagedDataSource;
yourRepeater.DataBind();

// and then the method
private ArrayList GetPageRange(int pagesToDisplay)
{
    ArrayList pages = new ArrayList();
    if (PagedDataSource.PageCount <= pagesToDisplay)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < PagedDataSource.PageCount; i++)
            pages.Add((i + 1).ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        if (PagedDataSource.CurrentPageIndex - (pagesToDisplay / 2) <= 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < pagesToDisplay; i++)
                pages.Add((i + 1).ToString());
        }
        else if (PagedDataSource.CurrentPageIndex + (pagesToDisplay / 2) >= PagedDataSource.PageCount)
        {
            for (int i = PagedDataSource.PageCount - pagesToDisplay; i < PagedDataSource.PageCount; i++)
                pages.Add((i + 1).ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = PagedDataSource.CurrentPageIndex - (pagesToDisplay / 2); i < PagedDataSource.CurrentPageIndex + (pagesToDisplay / 2); i++)
                pages.Add((i + 1).ToString());
        }
    }
    return pages;
}
```